# How to manually remove locks on files in Windows Server 2008 (64-Bit)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

We have recently migrated over to a 64-Bit Windows Server 2008.  Unfortunately, there are some poorly written apps that don't release the locks they retain on JPG files.  The obvious solution here is to fix the apps, and we're in the process. Anyway, prior to the migration we used an application called OpenFilesView found over at http://www.nirsoft.net/.

All that this app does is simply remove the handle a file has on it by other applications.  However, as expected, it does not work on the 64-bit version of the OS.  Does anyone know of a 64-bit equivalent?  Is there perhaps a built in command or M$ add-on that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Explorer from Microsoft allows you to close file handles opened by an application as well as many other functions. You can either search for an open handle using the Find menu, or you can see all the handles open by the selected process if you enable the lower panel in the view menu. Process explorer is available from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx.

Cheers

Dave